# Widget that takes preferences from app

Tags: android, widget, preferences

I created an app and it works fine.
The next step I want to do is to create a widget that will show some data from app, using settings stored as preferences. 
Please tell me, is it possible to make smth like this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to follow the dev guide about appwidgets to add a widget to your app. Then modify the RemoteViews from their example code by loading and using your sharedpreferences.
Best regards.